# What does /#/ symbol mean in the context of ${}?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, command-line-arguments

In the context of the following function

```
function foo { local d="d"; printf "%s" "${@/#/$d}"; }
```

what does the `/#/` mean?

When I call `foo a b c` it returns `dadbdc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `/#/` belongs to `"${@/#/$d}"`. It's about what [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) can do in Bash.

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
> The `pattern` is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. `parameter` is expanded and the longest match of `pattern` against its value is replaced with `string`. […] If `pattern` begins with `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of `parameter`. […]

`#` as `pattern` should be interpreted as `#` that anchors at the beginning, plus an empty string as the actual pattern to match. It matches an empty string at the beginning.

`string` itself undergoes parameter expansion (although the quoted fragment does not explicitly state this). In your code `$d` expands to `d`.

If it was `${parameter/#/$d}` then `d` would replace an empty string at the beginning of the expanded value of `parameter`. In other words `d` would be prefixed to the expanded value. This would work with `parameter` holding an empty string (the result would be just `d`), but not with `parameter` being unset (the result would still be empty like from any unset parameter, `d` would not be added).

In your code there is `@` in place of `parameter`. Simple `$@` expands to all positional parameters starting from one (or to nothing, if even the first one is unset). `"$@"` expands to all positional parameters, where each one behaves as if it was separately double-quoted. Similarly `${@/#/d}` expands to all positional parameters, where each one gets `d` in front; and if `$d` expands to `d` then `${@/#/$d}` will give the same result. Finally `"${@/#/$d}"` expands to all positional parameters, where each one gets `d` in front and behaves as if it was separately double-quoted.

So when you run `foo a b c`, `printf "%s" "${@/#/$d}"` is equivalent to

```
printf "%s" "da" "db" "dc"
```

Note the `${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax is *not* specified by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Answer (score 2):

`"${@/#/$d}"` is expanded by Bash in the following way:

1. `@` refers to the parameter array, so if you call a function `foo` like `foo "a b" c` then the parameter array has two entries `a b` and `c`.
2. `"${varname/pattern/replacement}"` (pattern substitution) replaces the first instance of `pattern` in the variable `varname` with `replacement`.
3. `#` in a pattern substitution matches the start of the variable value rather than the literal string "#".
4. `$d` is a simple variable reference, and will be expanded to the value of the `d` variable.

In summary, this will expand to each of the function parameters, then inserts the value of the `d` variable before each of them. Each of these parameters are printed with no formatting (and importantly no separators) by `printf`.

A good name for this function may be `prefix_join`, since it basically prefixes each of the arguments and then joins them.

Comment: Note: in the [*original* original code](https://superuser.com/revisions/1586997/1) the syntax was right, only the name of the function was inconsistent.